# How can I programmatically start an AccessibilityService?

Tags: android, application-settings, accessibilityservice

I'm using an **accessibility-service** to check which application I'm using **for-example** I am using **WhatsApp** and I am trying to get its package name and compare it with my database if the package exists in my database then I'm closing the app so that I can't use this app, I just working on my idea. It's been days since I got this problem and I can't find the solutions to my problems can anyone help me. Thank you

The Problems that I am facing are listed below:

1. Accessibility service is automatically closing when I try to close my app. If I don't close the app it's working fine. **For-example** If I close my main application the service will turn off. Is there any way to stop that?
2. When I found the package name in my database what I'm doing is taking the user on the main screen "Home Page". That is not a good way to do it, can someone help me with this one. I need to properly block that app.
3. Is there any way to close the application which I am trying to block from recent apps?

My code is listed below:

**Accessibility service class**

```
 override fun onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected() 
        val info = serviceInfo
        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED 
        info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT
        info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_INCLUDE_NOT_IMPORTANT_VIEWS
        info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REPORT_VIEW_IDS
        info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REQUEST_ENHANCED_WEB_ACCESSIBILITY
        info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_RETRIEVE_INTERACTIVE_WINDOWS
        info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK
        info.notificationTimeout = 100
        info.packageNames = null
        serviceInfo = info
 } 


 override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent) {

        if(AccessibilityEvent.eventTypeToString(event.eventType).contains("WINDOW")){
            val nodeInfo = event.source
            dfs(nodeInfo)
        }

        if (event.packageName != null) { 
            getAllBlockedApps(packageName = event.packageName.toString())
            return
        }
    }
```

**Block Application Code**

```
val startMain = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN) 
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
startMain.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
startMain.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS
startActivity(startMain)
```